# Beautiful soup simple python error with finding elements within elements?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, runtime-error

I've come across a BS4 error that gives no explanation, at least not one I understand, could someone help me know what it means?
here is the code:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    soup.prettify()
    container = soup.find('table', {'id': 'RmvMainTable'})
    containerlv2 = container.find('tr')
    # related_files = containerlv2[6].find('div')
    # print(related_files)
    for re_file in containerlv2[6].find('div'):
        print("lol")
```

and here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/user/Python projects/test/test3.py", line 162, in <module>
  for re_file in containerlv2[6].find('div'):
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 958, in __getitem__
  return self.attrs[key]
 KeyError: 6
```

if you notice the # out code it gives the exact same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`containerlv2` is a tag object, and it does not have 6 as key, therefore you got `KeyError: 6`

If you are trying to search for `div` tag in the 7th `tr` tag, the correct way should be:

```
containerlv2 = container.find_all('tr')
related_files = containerlv2[6].find('div')
```

First you use `find_all` to get all `tr` tags in `container` and put them into a list `containerlv2`, and then you search for `div` in the 7th tag of `containerlv2`

Answer (score 0):

```
containerlv2 = container.find('tr')
```

this will return a tag object, and you index a tag object like this

```
containerlv2[6]
```